# Calculate the function F(n) with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

Read the topic that I do not know what it is saying:
The function F (n) determined on non-negative integers as follows:
F (0) = 1; F (1) = 1; F (2n) = f (n); F (2n + 1) = F (n) + F (n + 1)
Calculated F (n) by recursion.
and my code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
double TINH_F(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
   {
      return 0;
   }
    if(n == 1)
    {
      return 1;
    }

     return (F(n+1) - F(2*n+1));
}
```

Comment: And what's the question? Does your code work as expected?

Answer (score 4):

This is obviously incorrect.  A recursive function calls *itself* and includes a stopping condition:

```
#include<iostream.h>
double TINH_F(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
   {
      return 0;
   }
    if(n == 1)
    {
      return 1;
    }

     // Note the function name change
     return (TINH_F(n+1) - TINH_F(2*n+1));
}
```

What should your function do if the integer passed in is negative?  Will the recursion still work?  Or should you throw an exception to indicate to callers that the contract is broken?

Comment: He also missed, that there two variants for even and odd values of 'n' ;)

Comment: You might want to empathize the part about the stopping condition, as there is none now really.

Comment: When does your recursion stop?

Comment: Yes there is: the checks for n=0 and n=1 are the stopping conditions.

Answer (score 2):

```
int f(int n)
{
    if (n<0) return -1; // check if n is positive
    if (n<=1) return 1; // we can catch the first two cases in a single condition

    int half = n/2;

    if (n % 2 == 0) return f(half); // if n is even
    else return f(half) + f(half+1); // if n is odd
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last case says

- F (n) = F (n+1) + F(2 * n + 1), for all n > 1

If you read the definition carefully, this case is not mentioned anywhere.

I believe you're being tricked by the naming of the parameter - you need four cases.

Let's break it down:

- F (0) = 1 (or 0 - your definition says 1, but the code says 0...)
- F (1) = 1
- F (2n) = F (n)
- F (2n + 1) = F (n) + F (n + 1)

The first two cases are trivial.

The third case says that if the argument - let's call it `m` - is even, the result is `F(m/2)`.

The fourth case says that if the argument `m` is odd, the result is `F(m/2) + F(m/2 + 1)`.
(Confirming the arithmetic left as an exercise.)

In C++:

```
unsigned int TINH_F(unsigned int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return TINH_F(n / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        return TINH_F(n/2) + TINH_F(n/2 + 1);
    }
}
```